# Positioning in android listview

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I'm having some trouble with the positioning in an android listview, the next activity isn't loading, while they are both in the manifest.

Here's my code:

```
package com.WNF;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Actiemenu extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources into Array
    String[] actiemenu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actiemenu);

    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.actiemenu, R.id.label,     actiemenu));

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

            switch(position) {
            case '0' :            
                Intent intent = new Intent(Actiemenu.this, Acties.class);
                intent.putExtra("extras", position);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case '1' :            
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(Actiemenu.this, Acties2.class);
                intent2.putExtra("extras", position);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
        }


      }
    });

}
}
```

The code to receive the intent is also present in Acties

```
package com.WNF;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Acties extends Activity{
// aanroepen van een bundle, kan je elke naam geven die je maar wilt, 
//zolang de bundle als de onCreate maar dezelfde naam hebben
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // de setContentView is niets meer dan de gegevens van de
//View ophalen uit de R.layout.naamvandeXML
        // Onthoud goed dat je dezelfde XMLs voor meerdere pagina's 
//kan gebruiken.
        setContentView(R.layout.acties1);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        i.getStringExtra("extras");
   }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong??
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm going to sleep now xD its 1:10 am here, i'll answer tomorrow if necessary ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch statement is incorrectly trying to match the *integer* position value to the *ASCII characters* `'0'` and `'1'`.  Since the ASCII value of `'0'` is 48 and the ASCII value of `'1'` is 49, nothing happens when you click the first two list items.

You should eliminate the single quotes and simply use integers:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    switch(position) {
    case 0: //Instead of '0' 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Actiemenu.this, Acties.class);
        intent.putExtra("extras", position);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 1: //Instead of '1'
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Actiemenu.this, Acties2.class);
        intent2.putExtra("extras", position);
        startActivity(intent2);
        break;
}
```